# Schedule jobs in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am assuming that someone has reserved 4:30 now and wants to save it to the server and notify the server from the server at 4:30.

I do not want to use the alarm system built into the smartphone.

I also watched Firebase cloud function lectures on YouTube and implemented them. And I've also seen CronJobs, which gets into the URL by alarm on time and executes the function. I have to set the time for the user and give an alarm to each individual.

Comment: There is currently no given mechanism in Cloud Functions to schedule a single job to run at a given time.  You will have to arrange that yourself.

Comment: Then what should I use one? do you have any idea with this to implement these things? for anything.

Comment: I don't use Firebase, but I assume you can use a cron job. You've mentioned them, did you try them? I assume it's just a question of calling a public endpoint with the appropriate access token?

Comment: Im new with firebase, and in the near future I will need to implement something like, I've been thinking in a node.js server with something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). So you can read the schedules from your firebase data and then FIRE the notification via node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward way of doing this, but you can go ahead and create a custom scheduler to work around it.  A great article with step by step instructions was released by the angularfirebase people at:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/scheduled-tasks-and-cron-jobs-with-firebase/

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is no longer accurate. As the other answer suggests, this is now available in firebase with pubsub functions

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at [schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) looks like you can do something like:

```
export scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes')
.onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
});
```