# How to send scheduled push notification using rest api in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

how to pass the date-time parameter in fcm body?
I tried passing event_time in the notification body but it is not working.

```
 {
        "registration_ids": [
            "fNsi-sHiQDSWcNdx5Y2Nf9:APA91bEewR3VbuPVJO3qFDlcmqS6rp5fZilITgZJfl61JOsje6OEP13RjhxAn-0JRzf0-u8Mg-OBAKxRKtKRtpeisZagHJZsNYa_zat--1iyemwUSxdZIMRt2jxfZMiZ9Od4mk2DmznG",
            "fyYtfww_QzOTVh1aFyOaTZ:APA91bFih7TD9Q04kb03Ju1zUJ66N_2yMwo2dUCr_ZJJs-NKv3AaEAimGV2lxm7kgIsVlJSXRmrau-VFZ_52AS9tqobl-vP7iXbOOT35kdEFVEROMotr4AiksD2b5vE_TWWyai3BbH9E"
        ],
        "notification": {
            "body": "killed",
            "title": "killed title",
            "android_channel_id": "push_notification",
            "sound": false
        },
        "data": {
            "body": "data body",
            "title": "Data",
            "_id": 34534
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share a little more context around where you set this? Hard to know options without a little more context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule FCM Notification using HTTP V1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614402/schedule-fcm-notification-using-http-v1)