# Creating dynamically scheduled functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, cron

I have a list of 10 time stamps which keeps on updating dynamically. In total there are 3 such lists for 3 users. I want to build a utility to trigger a function at the next upcoming time stamp. (preferably everything over server-less compute)

I am stuck in finding out how to achieve this over aws or firebase

Answer (score 2):

On Firebase/Google Cloud Functions the two most common options are *either* to store the schedule in a database and then periodically trigger a Cloud Function and run the tasks that are due, *or* to use Cloud Tasks to dynamically schedule a callback to a separate Cloud Function for each task.

I recommend also reading:

- Doug's blog post on [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)
- Fireship.io's tutorial on [Dynamic Scheduled Background Jobs in Firebase](https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/)
- [How can scheduled Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications be made outside of the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713668/how-can-scheduled-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications-be-made-outside-of-the/60714000#60714000)
- Previous [questions on dynamically scheduling functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=google-cloud-functions+dynamic+schedule+site:stackoverflow.com), as this has been covered quite well before.

**Update** (late 2022): there is now also a built-in way to schedule Cloud Functions dynamically: [enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions).

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, does your first option refer to a polling based solution? Keep calling a cloud function, check if any tasks are present in firestore with a due time that has passed (or is about to pass), and execute them - otherwise return and check again in a few minutes? If this is correct, it seems like the most expensive (i.t.o. firebase pricing for function executions) of the two options, right?

Comment: It depends on how often you execute the check, and I'd always recommend doing some back-of-napkin calculations on this overhead as Cloud Function invocations are really cheap. That said, the second option eliminates the polling altogether - so pick what you prefer.