# Expo React Native: How to set notification by date and time choosen by the user

Tags: expo

I created a todo app using the expo-notifications library and datatimepickermodal.

This is the code I set for the current day:

```
const scheduleTodoNotification = async (todo) => {
      
    // set trigger date and time todo.date if todo is today e.g 4/5/2023 1230AM
     const trigger = new Date (todo.date)
  
    try {
      await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: {
          title: "Alert! Tu hai un'attività da fare!",
          body: todo.text,
        },
        trigger,
      });
      console.log('Notificazione pianificata')

    } catch (error) {
      alert('The notification failed to schedule')
    }
  };
```

I'm not able to set the code to notify the user of the activities he has to do for each date and time the choosen.
How can I notify the user of the activity he has to perform on a day other than the current day?

Comment: take a look if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714000/9894625) helps you